# How to remove all models that are not contained in the current array in Realm

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, realm

I have the following case, I get data when loading the application, it is an array of `ChatUserPersonalConversationModel` models, I store this array in Realm as a separate model. What is the best way to do the following when I get an array and if the previous model is not contained in the resulting array, then I delete it from Realm.

I wrote the following code, it works for me, but I think that it can do better.

```
 func updateChatUserPersonalConversationModels(_ chatUserPersonalConversationModels: [ChatUserPersonalConversationModel]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            do {
                let realm = try Realm()
                let existChatUserPersonalConversationModels = realm.objects(ChatUserPersonalConversationModel.self)

                for existChatUserPersonalConversationModel in existChatUserPersonalConversationModels {
                    if !chatUserPersonalConversationModels.contains(where: { (newChatUserPersonalConversationModel) -> Bool in
                        return newChatUserPersonalConversationModel.id == existChatUserPersonalConversationModel.id
                    }) {
                        try realm.write {
                            realm.delete(existChatUserPersonalConversationModel)
                        }
                    }
                }

                try realm.write {
                    realm.add(chatUserPersonalConversationModels, update: true)
                }
            } catch {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realm doesn't have any built-in functionality to achieve what you want. An alternative to what you have is to leverage Swift's `Set` type.

First, you should make sure equality and the hash value property are defined for your model class, and you should probably have a primary key (which seems to be `id`).

Next, turn your arrays of existing and new models into `Set`s. `Set` has an initializer that takes any sequence of objects, so you can pass arrays and Realm `List`s alike into it.

Next, use the `subtract(_:)` method on `Set` to get a new set containing just the elements you want to delete:

```
// itemsToDelete contains models in oldModels that aren't in newModels
let itemsToDelete = oldModels.subtract(newModels)
```

Finally, you can use the Realm `delete(_:)` method that takes a sequence to delete all the obsolete models at once:

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.delete(itemsToDelete)
}
```

I hope this helps. Note that this isn't a panacea; if your arrays are huge you may want to consider whether this approach uses too much memory.

Comment: this worked for me, i only had to override isEqual on my model